# How to apply a function to a sequence multiple times

Tags: clojure

I am working on some Lisp [exercises](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html) using Clojure. I am trying to work these exercises without taking advantage of vectors and some Clojure functions.

This function

```
(defn rev-seq
    [s1]
    (concat (pop s1) (list (peek s1))))
```

puts the first element of a list at the end. I want to call this function as many times as it takes to reverse the list (without calling Clojure's `reverse` function).

I am not sure what to use in its place. I have experimented with map, apply, and repeat with no success. I would rather have a way to think differently about this than a straight answer, but I am not asking for a discussion.

Comment: As it turns out (#(into () %1) '(a b c d)) reversed the list.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that (into () '(a b c d)) also reverses the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think you'll need to convert rev-seq to use `first`/`rest` rather than `peek`/`pop` if you want to work on general sequences - at leas in Clojure 1.4 `peek`/`pop` seems to require a PersistentStack:

```
(defn rev-seq
  [s1]
  (concat (rest s1) (list (first s1))))
```

Then you should probably note that applying this function repeatedly will "cycle" a list rather than reversing it. You can see that if you look at the result of a small number of applications using `iterate`:

```
(def s '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(nth (iterate rev-seq s) 3)
=> (4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3)
```

An option that would work  is to reverse with a recursive function:

```
(defn reverse-seq [s]
  (concat (reverse (next s)) (list (first s))))

(reverse-seq s)
=> (9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Or alternatively you can do a reverse using the technique in clojure.core:

```
(defn reverse-seq [s]
  (reduce conj () s))

(reverse-seq s)
=> (9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Hope this gives you some ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is powerful!
I translated
[the solution](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/p05.lisp)
into Clojure.

```
(defn- inverte-aux
  [lista resto]
  (if lista
    (recur (next lista) (cons (first lista) resto))
    resto))

(defn inverte
  [lista]
  (inverte-aux lista nil))

user> (inverte [4 3 2 1 3])
(3 1 2 3 4)
```